# Release Compilation Error VS010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compilation, release

When I try to run my code in Visual Studio 2010 in release mode I get:

1>cl : error D8045: The C file "..\eph_manager.c" cannot be compiled with the/clr-Option

I don't really understand what happens there. I needed to change that to make it compile in debug (where I have 0 errors).

Comment: The traditional mistake is making a configuration change in the Debug configuration but then forgetting to make the same change in the Release configuration.  If /clr is in fact intended for the project (don't make us guess) then just right-click the .c file in the Solution Explorer window, Properties, ensure you have the Release configuration selected and change the setting.

Comment: I had made the change in the solution properties but not in each of the *.c files... Thanks a lot!
How can I accept that as an aswer?